# How to recreate "Scroll Capture" effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, locking

First, thank you for taking the time to check this post.

I am looking to recreate an effect I've seen a number of times but accurately presented [here](https://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/).

When scrolling down the page, the user reaches a video element (there are a handful of these elements on the page) and when said element reaches the top of the screen, it requires a certain amount of scrolling to take place before leaving the element. With the element being full view height, it creates a sort of "locking" effect, despite the scroll bar clearly shows I am still scrolling.

How is this interaction achieved?

The content of the element, the blur, the video, the animated text all aside, how would one recreate this effect on a long page with a 100vh div and css/js? (GREATLY prefer no jQuery, just vanilla JS)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clever use of `position: sticky`. You put your sticky `<div>` inside a `position: relative` container. When the viewport reaches the sticky `<div>`, it'll act as if it's `position: fixed`. If I'm reading the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#sticky-pos) correctly, the `<div>` won't ever be offset outside the bounds of its containing block (the `position: relative` container) so as soon as that starts to scroll out of the viewport the  will be pushed up with it.

From the spec:

> Intersection between the stickily positioned element and the bottom of the sticky-constraint rectangle limits movement in any direction, so the offset never pushes the stickily positioned element outside of its containing block. However, when the element is free to move within its containing block as the page is scrolled, it appears to be pinned to the relevant flow root edges, similarly to a fixed position element.

Here's a little [demo](http://output.jsbin.com/hosopifega).

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much for your insight, that was exactly what I'm looking for.